# regular expression for file name

Tags: java, regex

I have files in the format *C:\Temp\myfile_124.txt*

I need a regular expression which will give me just the number "**124**" that is whatever is there after the underscore and before the extension.

I tried a number of ways, latest is

```
(.+[0-9]{18,})(_[0-9]+)?\\.txt$
```

I am not getting the desired output. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
       Matcher matcher = FILE_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(filename);
        if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() == 2) {
            try {
                String index = matcher.group(2);
                if (index != null) {
                    return Integer.parseInt(index.substring(1));
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
```

Comment: The first group specifies you should have 18 digits in your filename, which you do not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part `[0-9]{18,}` states you have atleast 18 digits which you don't have.

Usually with regex its a good idea to make the expression as simple as possible. I suggest trying

```
_([0-9]+)?\\.txt$
```

Note: you have to call find() to make it perform the lookup, otherwise it says "No match found"

---

This example

```
String s = "C:\\Temp\\myfile_124.txt";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\d+)\\.txt$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find())
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
        System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
```

prints

```
0: _124.txt
1: 124
```

Comment: I had given 18 as a length since the file name length can go up.other than that what was wrong in mine?especially after the underscore portion?

Comment: You also specified it can only be between [0-9] which means 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9 and you have other letters like C,:,\,T,e,m,p,\,m,y,f,i,l,e

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you: `(?:.*_)(\d+)\.txt`
The result is in the match group.
This one uses positive lookahead and will only match the number: `\d+(?=\.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

```
.*_([1-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

The group 1 will contain the desired output.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?32q30)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
^.*_\([^\.]*\)\..*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*_([0-9]+)\.txt
```

This should work too. Of course you should double escape for Java.